# XS community 6.1.1 auto close apps on iOS simulator 8.1 after deploy

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, xamarin-studio

When I debug and deploy Xamarin.iOS native app to iOS simulator 8.1 through XS(in Mac), it installs app to simulator but it closes automatically after installation. Though app deployment on iOS simulator 10 works fine. This problem is occurred after updating XS to latest version and iOS SDK update to latest version. My iOS app deployment target is 8.0. Also I made sure that Entitlements.plist is empty.

NOTE: Xcode 8 does successful installation on iOS simulator 8.1 and works fine.

Anyone knows why this problem occurs and how to resolve it ?

Comment: You should report this as a bug on [Xamarin's bug reporting system](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com)

Answer (score 0):

Clean the project, recompile it and run on simulator.
Additionally, open simulator logs using `Cmd + /` hotkey and see what exactly is being printed to the simulator logs when you launch your app.

I've seen similar problems which were related to the app crash on launch actually.